# WPF Grid Expander Listview vertical scrollbar missing

Tags: wpf, listview, grid, scrollbar, expander

I have the following UI element tree:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid>
<Expander>
    <ListView/>
</Expander>
<Expander>
    <ListView/>
</Expander>
</Grid>
```

I have set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True", ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto", ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto". However, the content of the ListView extends beyond the widow size without showing any vertical scroll bar at all. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Auto` will fit to the content (that's why it stretches). So you need to change `Height` to `*` to be able to take any available space.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: That helps. Thanks.

Comment: @KokHowTeh, you can accept an answer if you find it solved your problem. (didn't see you accept any answer for all your questions, so just in case..)

Comment: I just found out this solves this specific question. However, it leads to another problem as indicated in my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917247/wpf-grid-expander-listview-fills-up-the-space-when-gridsplitter-moves